# Whats wrong with my query

Tags: mysql

`MySQL` wrote:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELETE FROM surebet.fork_bet WHERE surebet_fork_key NOT IN
>   (SELECT super' at line 2

```
DELETE
FROM superbet.fork_bet
WHERE superbet_fork_key
NOT IN (
    SELECT superbet_fork_key 
    FROM fork_bet_temp
    WHERE fork_bet_temp.superbet_fork_key = fork_bet.superbet_fork_key
);
```

Comment: Is the table something other than MyISAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM superbet.fork_bet
WHERE superbet.fork_key
NOT IN (
    SELECT superbet_fork_key 
    FROM fork_bet_temp
    WHERE fork_bet_temp.superbet_fork_key = fork_bet_temp.superbet_fork_key
);
```

Changed the WHERE clause on both, looks like you tried to do an underscore where a period was required, and you named the second WHERE incorrectly, fork_bet isn't the table, fork_bet_temp is.

If you get an error with that, post your table layout.

Comment: I didn't down vote the question, but expect it was down voted for lack of table layout.  Would be best to do as @Jonathan suggests and post the layout...

Comment: fork_bet(
  superbet_fork_key VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  superbet_bet_key VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (superbet_fork_key, superbet_bet_key)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 24
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
COMMENT = '';

Comment: It would be better to edit your original question rather than post in a comment.

Comment: Opps. i think i know error reason. This query in my .sql file and me loading to mysql_query() by file_get_contents() and on any second row in this file MySQL show error. This is error not in query. But thank you for your reply.